# ModelState stays valid even if the required attributes are empty in the .NET Framework Web API 4.7.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.7.2

I have a strange situation, and none of the existing solutions help

I have this model in the .NET Framework Web API

```
public partial class RequestData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string VendorName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Memo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsToBePrinted { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string AccountType { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Nullable<double> Amount { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsProcessed { get; set; }
    public string Ticket { get; set; }
    public string Response { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Updated { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Nullable<int> RequestType { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string TxnId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string EditSequence { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ListID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string TxnLineId { get; set; }
}
```

I have a POST controller that uses this model

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostNewRequest([FromBody] RequestData requestData)
    {
        try
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
                //Your code if the field is invalid
            } else {
                //Your code if the field is valid
            }
```

But when I send empty values for the required fields (I use SOAP UI) and those values come to a controller as NULL values, the ModelState stays valid

What am I doing wrong, and how else can I take advantage of the Required attributes/annotators?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: `if (ModelState.IsValid && requestData != null) { // valid in here }`

Comment: @Ihdina thank you but it doesn't solve it

Comment: Look at here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: @Ihdina still not working

Comment: Look at `Method 2` example in https://stacktuts.com/how-to-fix-get-error-message-if-modelstate-isvalid-fails-in-c

Comment: @Ihdina that method is irrelevant as ModelState.IsValid is always true no matter what

Comment: You need to make them nullable like ``string?``

Comment: @sa-es-ir the is nulable to begin with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. I mistakenly referenced the entity from an EF project instead of the model

After I added a line that would specify what exact model I had to use, it all worked

```
using RequestData = QuickbooksDesktopAPI.Models.RequestData;
```